# Using regular expressions to get a word in between two Key words

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, regex

It has been a while since I have used regular expressions and I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is possible.  I have a program that sends automated response regarding a particular file and I'd like to grab the text between two words I know will never change. In this example those words are "regarding" and "sent"

```
Dim subject As String = "Information regarding John Doe sent."
Dim name As String = Regex.IsMatch(subject, "")
```

So in this case I'd like to be able to get just "John Doe".  Every regexp I'm coming up with includes the words "regarding" and "sent".  How can I use those words as the boundaries but not include them in the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `"Information regarding "` and `"sent."` never change, you can use a capturing  group to get `"John Doe"`:

```
^Information regarding (.+) sent.$
```

And you use it this way:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("^Information regarding (.+) sent.$")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(subject)
```

Now, it should only match once, and you can get the group from the Groups property of the match:

```
For Each match As Match In matches  
  Dim groups As GroupCollection = match.Groups
  Console.WriteLine(groups.Item(1).Value) // prints John Doe
Next
```

Comment: That last line should have been `Console.WriteLine(groups.Item(1).Value)` - group #0 is the whole match, while group #1 is the first capturing (parenthesized) group.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should essentially look like this:

```
.*regarding (.+) sent.*
```

And the data you're looking for will be in the first capture variable ($1 in Perl).

Answer (score 0):

While matching all the groups is a way of doing, I would use two non matching groups and one named froup so that it would only ever return the group that you wanted.  This would give you the regex:

```
(?:regarding )(?<filename>.*)(?: sent)
```

this would give you the ability to call the filename from the groups for example

```
Dim rx As New Regex("(?:regarding )(?<filename>.*)(?: sent)", _
           RegexOptions.Compiled )
Dim text As String = "Information regarding John Doe sent."
Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(text)
'The lazy way to get match, should print 'John Doe'
Console.WriteLine( matches[0].Groups.Item("filename").Value )
```

A good resource for Regex is found on the msdn site [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)